# Flutter, unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, dependencies, flutter

I'm trying to build a simple flutter application.

While trying to run the application in my android studio 3.0.1, the following error is displayed. Latest build tools and platform is installed.

> Resolving dependencies... Finished with error:
>
> - Error running Gradle: Unable to download needed Android SDK components, as the following licenses have not been accepted: Android
>     SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3, Android SDK Platform 25
>
> To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal:
>   flutter doctor --android-licenses

When tried to run the above code, the below-mentioned error is displayed.

> Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.

Hope anyone can help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14942#issuecomment-369319232 might be related

Answer (score 1):

[Change sdk.dir in local.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSCHq.png)

[image]
Problem was with sdk path in local.properties. By default its pointing to different location. It works for me when change android sdk home dir in sdk.dir

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the location of SDK

Make sure its not in folder with spaces like C:\John Doe\SDK

Update your SDK and try again this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 0):

```
subprojects {
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "27.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

}

It fixed for me by adding this to build.gradle in android folder.

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

If the problem still exists 
Make sure your sdk is not in folder with spaces like `C:\Windows\Users\Rahul Raj\Android\SDK` Even If The Problem exists try checking the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` shows your sdk path